# I'm trying to load a .txt file using np.loadtxt on python but it gives me always the same error

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

```
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import scipy
import pandas

np.loadtxt('ptcatenaria.txt', dtype = float, delimiter = ',')
```

this is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<tmp 1>", line 6, in <module>
    np.loadtxt('ptcatenaria.txt', dtype = float, delimiter = ',')
  File "c:\users\alber\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 961, in loadtxt
    fh = np.lib._datasource.open(fname, 'rt', encoding=encoding)
  File "c:\users\alber\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\_datasource.py", line 195, in open
    return ds.open(path, mode, encoding=encoding, newline=newline)
  File "c:\users\alber\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\_datasource.py", line 535, in open
    raise IOError("%s not found." % path)
OSError: ptcatenaria.txt not found
```

Comment: Is the file in the same directory as of the code?

Comment: "OSError: ptcatenaria.txt not found"